# Loops positioning and multiplying

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

this might be easy for some but as i'm learning I'm kind of confused here, you see:

```
                int mult[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
                changeA.get(changeA.size()-1);
                for (int i = 0; i < mult.length; i++) {
                    int fullChange=((changeA.size()-1)*mult[i]);
                    System.out.println("changeA: "+ (changeA.size()-1) +".");
                    System.out.println("fullChange: "+fullChange);}
```

This is a part of a code I've been doing, the problem I have here is in my ArrayList. What I want to do is:

1. Grab the last item from the list which I do here:

   int fullChange=((changeA.size()-1)*mult[i]);
2. Then multiply it by the upper Array which I also do in the same line.
3. Print it (I'll grab the output to do some other stuff along the way but as I'm having problems solving this issue I can't move forward).

The problem comes when the problem explicitly says: **In the least amount of coins/bills**. So my code has to grab the last item in the list which is determined from an upper decision that fills the ArrayList. But my code doesn't do that, what my code does is grab the 2nd latest item in the list and multiplies it giving me the correct answer but not in the right amount of coins.
Here's an example

> Let's say that you buy a coke for 5 dollars, you pay it with a 10 dollar bill. So the change would be a 5 dollars bill in the least amount of coins/bills. If they don't have a 5 dollar bill they would give you 5 $1 dollar bill. So on and so forth.

Here's an output:
[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26KBa.png)

I also must say that the last 2 lines of the upper code are for testing and assuring my point. Thanks in advance

edit:
this is what comes after the code above:

```
if (fullChange==change) {
                        System.out.println("El cambio es: "+fullChange+" en monedas de: "+changeA.get(changeA.size()-1)+" con un total de: "+mult[i]+" monedas");
                        break;
                    }
```

so in mult[i] instead of giving me 1 it gives me 5 (using the example above)

Comment: Am I understanding your question right:
1. You are asked for an amount e.g. 72 euro.
2. You pay 80.
3. You get back 8, BUT in the least amount of coins?

And you have to write the code that does step 3?

Comment: How do I grab the latest value in the array and multiply it with the other array in the right way, because my code doesn’t grab the latest but the 2nd latest

Comment: @rinormaloku yes, but if you see the picture It doesn’t give me the least amount of coins but the 2nd least amount

Comment: i'll edit it so maybe you'll understand me better :)

Comment: We need some limits. E.g. what type of coins do we have? (1,2) Can the payment be in cents or in Banknotes (5, 10)... What would the maximum value be? And what the minimum? Can you give 1000 payment for 1 dollar bill?

Comment: @rinormaloku well in this example it'll be in banknotes in the minimimun which is 5. so 5*1= 5 and the 1 it's what mult[i] should print me but it doesn't, it prints 2. Am I explaining?

Comment: @sarquamon Also what you are doing is: Multiplying the size of changeA with the numbers in the array **mult**. you could simplify the code and achieve the same with for(i=1; i<=10; i++), But I don't think that's what you want. You most prolly want to:  int fullChange = changeA.get(changeA.size()-i) * j; the J would be another loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question right this should be the solution:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> changeA = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(5);
        add(10);
        add(20);
        add(50);
        add(100);
    }};

    int change = 10;
    outer: for (int i = changeA.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            int fullChange = changeA.get(i) * j;
            System.out.println("changeA: " + changeA.get(i) + ".");
            System.out.println("fullChange: " + fullChange);
            if (fullChange==change) {
                System.out.println("El cambio es: "+fullChange+" en monedas de: "+
                        changeA.get(i)+" con un total de: "+j+" monedas");
                break outer;
            }

        }
    }
```

With minimal change possible to your code.

Comment: after loosing a lot of files about a year or so ago i remembered i had asked about this a long time ago, and thank you so much dude, your code even helped me get back a lot of my code that was lost, thank you so much :3